# Using Aiohttp with Proxy

Tags: python, asynchronous, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I am trying to use async to get the HTML from a list of urls (identified by ids). I need to use a proxy.

I am trying to use aiohttp with proxies like below:

```
import asyncio
import aiohttp
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

ids = ['1', '2', '3']

async def fetch(session, id):
    print('Starting {}'.format(id))
    url = f'https://www.testing.com/{id}'

    async with session.get(url) as response:
        return BeautifulSoup(await response.content, 'html.parser')

async def main(id):
    proxydict = {"http": 'xx.xx.x.xx:xxxx', "https": 'xx.xx.xxx.xx:xxxx'}
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession(proxy=proxydict) as session:
        soup = await fetch(session, id)
        if 'No record found' in soup.title.text:
            print(id, 'na')


loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
future = [asyncio.ensure_future(main(id)) for id in ids]


loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.wait(future))
```

According to an issue here: https://github.com/aio-libs/aiohttp/pull/2582 it seems like `ClientSession(proxy=proxydict)` should work.

However, I am getting an error `"__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'proxy'"`

Any idea what I should do to resolve this please?
Thank you.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

You can set the proxy configuration inside the session.get call:

```
async with session.get(url, proxy=your_proxy_url) as response:
    return BeautifulSoup(await response.content, 'html.parser')
```

If your proxy requires authentication, you can set it in the url of your proxy like this:

```
proxy = 'http://your_user:your_password@your_proxy_url:your_proxy_port'
async with session.get(url, proxy=proxy) as response:
    return BeautifulSoup(await response.content, 'html.parser')
```

or:

```
proxy = 'http://your_proxy_url:your_proxy_port'
proxy_auth = aiohttp.BasicAuth('your_user', 'your_password')
async with session.get(url, proxy=proxy, proxy_auth=proxy_auth) as response:
    return BeautifulSoup(await response.content, 'html.parser')
```

For more details look at [here](http://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/client_advanced.html#proxy-support)

Comment: If you are looking to connect to a `.onion` site, you can find the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55191914/how-to-connect-to-onion-sites-using-python-aiohttp)

Answer (score 6):

Silly me - after reading the documentation by @Milan Velebit I realised the variable should be `trust_env=True` instead of **proxy** or **proxies**.   Proxies information should be from/set in the HTTP_PROXY /
HTTPS_PROXY environment variables.

Answer (score 0):

As per their [documentation](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/client_reference.html#aiohttp.ClientSession), there really is no **proxy** param, instead use **proxies**.

Comment: Unfortunately same issue: `TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'proxies'`