# How to connect to .onion sites using python aiohttp?

Tags: python-3.x, python-asyncio, tor, aiohttp, socks

I am trying to connect to a `.onion` site using python.  I have tor running on port 9050 and I am getting the following error:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/jane/code/test/test.py", line 15, in main
    res = await fetch(session, id)
  File "/Users/jane/code/test/test.py", line 9, in fetch
    async with session.get(url) as res:
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/aiohttp/client.py", line 1005, in __aenter__
    self._resp = await self._coro
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/aiohttp/client.py", line 476, in _request
    timeout=real_timeout
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 522, in connect
    proto = await self._create_connection(req, traces, timeout)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 854, in _create_connection
    req, traces, timeout)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/aiohttp/connector.py", line 959, in _create_direct_connection
    raise ClientConnectorError(req.connection_key, exc) from exc
aiohttp.client_exceptions.ClientConnectorError: Cannot connect to host intelex7ny6coqno.onion:80 ssl:None [nodename nor servname provided, or not known]
```

The code:

```
import asyncio
import aiohttp
from aiohttp_socks import SocksConnector

async def fetch(session, id):
    print('Starting {}'.format(id))
    url = 'http://intelex7ny6coqno.onion/topic/{}'.format(id)
    async with session.get(url) as res:
        return res.text

async def main(id):
    connector = SocksConnector.from_url('socks5://localhost:9050')
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession(connector=connector) as session:
        res = await fetch(session, id)
        print(res)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    ids = ['10', '11', '12']
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()

    future = [asyncio.ensure_future(main(id)) for id in ids]
    loop.run_until_complete(asyncio.wait(future))
```

This code works fine:

```
import requests
session = requests.session()
session.proxies['http'] = 'socks5h://localhost:9050'
session.proxies['https'] = 'socks5h://localhost:9050'
headers = {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:60.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/60.0',
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
}
res = session.get(url, headers=headers)
print(res)
```

Why am I getting `Cannot connect to host intelex7ny6coqno.onion:80 ssl:None [nodename nor servname provided, or not known]`?

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default it appears to be using the local DNS resolver to asynchronously resolve hostnames.  When using requests `socks5h` you are getting DNS resolution over SOCKS (Tor).

Adding [rdns](https://github.com/romis2012/aiohttp-socks/blob/0.2.2/aiohttp_socks/connector.py#L27)=True appears to work for .onion addresses:

```
connector = SocksConnector.from_url('socks5://localhost:9050', rdns=True)
```